# Русские символы в кодировке codeigniter

Tags: кодировка, codeigniter

Всем привет!

Не получается в CI отправить русские символы, хотя в классе указана кодировка UTF-8. гуглил, но решения не нашел. Помогите.

Comment: хотелось бы подробностей. что делали, что получалось?

Comment: Имеется ввиду стандартный класс email от CI. Как везде указано, что отправка писем с кирилицей не поддерживается. Ломаю голову, что можно сделать.